# Web App Bot throws invalid status code 'Unauthorized' on Facebook Channel

Tags: facebook, azure, asp.net-core, botframework

I'm developing a Facebook with the Microsoft.Bot.Builder Framework (4.2.2)
The Bot Works on emulator and on Azure with the "Test in Web Chat" Really fine. But on the Facebook Channel I get an "There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code InternalServerError"

My log stream says:

```
     019-04-12 13:23:22.154 +00:00 [Information] 
     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request starting 
     HTTP/1.1 POST 
     http://thomasreigltestbot1995.azurewebsites.net/api/messages 
     application/json; charset=utf-8 688
     2019-04-12 13:23:22.155 +00:00 [Information] 
     Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.IAdapterIntegration: Received an 
     incoming activity.  ActivityId: Vg2USjaJGCZ1Ib_- 
    LTftnL9F6qg_DCJaV3XbIqGzSpisuO10eYLezkjHJxSVcYAAUWQvynDJbUyfvyBgN30B3w
     2019-04-12 13:23:22.155 +00:00 [Information] 
     Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.IAdapterIntegration: Sending 
     activity.  ReplyToId: Vg2USjaJGCZ1Ib_- 
    LTftnL9F6qg_DCJaV3XbIqGzSpisuO10eYLezkjHJxSVcYAAUWQvynDJbUyfvyBgN30B3w
     2019-04-12 13:23:22.388 +00:00 [Error] 
     Facebook_Events_Bot.FacebookEventsBot: Exception caught : 
     Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an 
     invalid status code 'Unauthorized'at 
     Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.
```

This is my simple Bot from this repo:

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/23.facebook-events

```
public class FacebookEventsBot : IBot
{
    private const string DialogId = "question";

    /// </summary>
    private readonly DialogSet _dialogs;
    private Tuple<int, string> tuple;

    public FacebookEventsBot(BotAccessors accessors)
    {
        if (accessors == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(accessors));
        }

        _dialogs = new DialogSet(accessors.ConversationDialogState);
        _dialogs.Add(new AttachmentPrompt(DialogId));
    }

    public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        const string facebookPageNameOption = "Facebook Page Name";
        const string quickRepliesOption = "Quick Replies";
        const string postBackOption = "PostBack";

        if (turnContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(turnContext));
        }

        // Check if we are on the Facebook channel.
        if (turnContext.Activity.ChannelId == Channel.Channels.Facebook)
        {
            // Analyze Facebook payload from channel data.
            ProcessFacebookPayload(turnContext.Activity.ChannelData);

            // Initially the bot offers to showcase 3 Facebook features: Quick replies, PostBack and getting the Facebook Page Name.
            // Below we also show how to get the messaging_optin payload separately as well.
            switch (turnContext.Activity.Text)
            {
                // Here we showcase how to obtain the Facebook page name.
                // This can be useful for the Facebook multi-page support provided by the Bot Framework.
                // The Facebook page name from which the message comes from is in turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Name.
                case facebookPageNameOption:
                    {
                        var reply = turnContext.Activity.CreateReply($"This message comes from the following Facebook Page: {turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Name}");
                        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply);
                        break;
                    }

                // Here we send a HeroCard with 2 options that will trigger a Facebook PostBack.
                case postBackOption:
                    {
                        var dialogContext = await _dialogs.CreateContextAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
                        var results = await dialogContext.ContinueDialogAsync(cancellationToken);

                        var card = new HeroCard
                        {
                            Text = "Is 42 the answer to the ultimate question of Life, the Universe, and Everything?",
                            Buttons = new List<CardAction>
                                {
                                    new CardAction() { Title = "Yes", Type = ActionTypes.PostBack, Value = "Yes" },
                                    new CardAction() { Title = "No", Type = ActionTypes.PostBack, Value = "No" },
                                },
                        };

                        var reply = turnContext.Activity.CreateReply();
                        reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment> { card.ToAttachment() };
                        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply);

                        break;
                    }

                // By default we offer the users different actions that the bot supports, through quick replies.
                case quickRepliesOption:
                default:
                    {
                        var reply = turnContext.Activity.CreateReply("What Facebook feature would you like to try? Here are some quick replies to choose from!");
                        reply.SuggestedActions = new SuggestedActions()
                        {
                            Actions = new List<CardAction>()
                            {
                                new CardAction() { Title = quickRepliesOption, Type = ActionTypes.PostBack, Value = quickRepliesOption },
                                new CardAction() { Title = facebookPageNameOption, Type = ActionTypes.PostBack, Value = facebookPageNameOption },
                                new CardAction() { Title = postBackOption, Type = ActionTypes.PostBack, Value = postBackOption },
                            },
                        };
                        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply);
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Check if we are on the Facebook channel.
            if (turnContext.Activity.ChannelId == Channel.Channels.Facebook)
            {
                // Here we can check for messaging_optin webhook event.
                // Facebook Documentation for Message optin:
                // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events/messaging_optins/
            }

            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"Received activity of type {turnContext.Activity.Type}.");
        }
    }

    private void ProcessFacebookPayload(object channelData)
    {
        // At this point we know we are on Facebook channel, and can consume the Facebook custom payload
        // present in channelData.
        var facebookPayload = (channelData as JObject)?.ToObject<FacebookPayload>();

        if (facebookPayload != null)
        {
            // PostBack
            if (facebookPayload.PostBack != null)
            {
                OnFacebookPostBack(facebookPayload.PostBack);
            }

            // Optin
            else if (facebookPayload.Optin != null)
            {
                OnFacebookOptin(facebookPayload.Optin);
            }

            // Quick reply
            else if (facebookPayload.Message?.QuickReply != null)
            {
                OnFacebookQuickReply(facebookPayload.Message.QuickReply);
            }

            // TODO: Handle other events that you're interested in...
        }
    }

    private void OnFacebookOptin(FacebookOptin optin)
    {
        // TODO: Your optin event handling logic here...
    }

    private void OnFacebookPostBack(FacebookPostback postBack)
    {
        // TODO: Your PostBack handling logic here...
    }

    private void OnFacebookQuickReply(FacebookQuickReply quickReply)
    {
        // TODO: Your quick reply event handling logic here...
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that Facebook was set up correctly?